# Multiple OpenID sign-in solution for php

Tags: php, openid

I'm developing a website and I want to integrate multiple OpenID choices (e.g. Facebook, Google, Yahoo, myOpenID, etc.) for my website's login. I looked around and found a few solutions but so far I couldn't find one with these criterias:

- Easy Install and usage
- Lightweight
- Good documentation (or perhaps ideally a tutorial) for its usage
- Some features to grab data from the target database (for instance getting the user avatar and showing it on my website)
- Recognizing duplicate users (I mean if I sign in with my Facebook account and Google account, if possible it should recognize that I'm the same person)

The first 3 are very important for me but the last 2 are not **that** important.

A good example of a sign-in widget for my website (what I have in mind) is [Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage)

Comment: It's not free (it's got limit), it's not that easy to install and it doesn't have a very good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my other question, Dimme answered with this awesome link:

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html